# Windows server 2008 rejecting packets from client

Tags: windows-server-2008

We deployed a server application in .NET 4.0 that is going to run on Windows Server 2008 R2. Strangely, the clients cannot connect to the server given the server's IP and the server port.

I've ran wireshark diagnostics on the server computer and verified that the packets are arriving to the NIC without any issue so it seems Windows Server 2008 is the culprit here.

I've tried to temporarily disable the firewall and add the server port into inbound/outbound rule but it still doesn't solve the issue.

How can I solve this issue?

Edit: Sorry, bad choice of word. The server is not "rejecting" the packets, the server is just failing to respond.

Comment: What's the server responding with?  By saying 'rejecting', you're implying that the server is responding with TCP RST packets, but is that the case?  Or is it just failing to respond?

Comment: The application opens up a TCP socket and starts listening on it. When the client tries to send a packet, the application on the server's end never gets it. But when I ran wireshark and checked the TCP stream, the content definitely arrived to the server's NIC but the OS seems to be blocking it.

Comment: Turn off all firewalling on the machine and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I did exactly that and well, no luck D:

Comment: Did you check if the server is replying to the packets?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz As said in the question, the server (NIC) receives the packets but does not reply because the server application isn't receiving the packet.

Comment: @l46kok: I fear that he may be incorrectly inferring that from the fact that the application doesn't see the connection. This could happen if the server sends the reply to the wrong place and it doesn't get to the destination or doesn't get NATted.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Maybe I'm doing a bad job at explaining the problem here D:. First of all, server is not behind an NAT. The server application that I wrote opens a TCP socket and starts running on port 5055. When the client tries to connect to the server to port 5055, the server application never receives any packets from the client, so the server application can't send a response out to begin with. This is where I ran wireshark diagnostics to make sure that the server computer itself is receiving the packets.

Comment: Turns out that the server is receiving the packets so this is where it led me to believe that it's actually the O/S (Win server 2008) blocking the packets being sent to the server application.

Comment: @l46kok: You're still badly confusing things. For example, you say "the server application never receives any packets from the client". But of course it doesn't. Applications *never* receive TCP packets. They receive connections and chunks of bytes. If the server is not behind NAT, why do you talk about an "external IP"? External to what? And I asked if the *server* sent a response, not the application. The application will certainly not see the connection if the server's reply packets aren't getting through because the TCP handshake won't complete. We are talking past each other.

Comment: Your next troubleshooting step is to determine if the server is replying to the packets. If it is, then see if those replies are correct (particularly the destination hardware address) and then see if they are actually getting to their destination. Most likely, the server is replying to those packets, the replies are not getting through, and therefore the TCP handshake never completes. This causes the application to not see them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OH ok. I'm pretty new to this stuff so I apologize about my ignorance. From looking at the wireshark packet, yes the TCP handshake seems to be completing as server is sending a reply back to the client. This is a snapshot of wireshark diagnostics from the client's perspective. http://imageshack.us/a/img837/1411/14289430.png. I don't know why I wrote external IP up there, I guess I was zoning out.

Comment: And this one from the server's perspective http://imageshack.us/a/img571/5593/79502371.png

Edit: Wrong link. Updated with new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My god, this was a pretty big gotcha for me. The server's NIC has two ip addresses and for Windows 2008, the inbound/outbound rule only applies for the IP that is closest to the default gateway.

I went ahead and made it so that the clients connect to the other server's IP and bam, everything works